# ASP.NET certificate signing xml/pkcs algorithm change. SHA1 to SHA256

Tags: asp.net, certificate, sha1, sha256

We are upgrading our website from ASP.NET 4.61 to 4.8 and running into the following issue with our certificate. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/retargeting/4.5.2-4.7.1#default-signedxml-and-signedxms-algorithms-changed-to-sha256

Our cert is SHA2 but the SignedXML and SignedXMS algorithm is SHA1 in the cert. I would like to get our cert re-issued with SignedXML and SignedXMS algorithms as SHA256, which is the default for .NET 4.71 and up.

*Question is, would the re-issued cert work in our current production environment with .NET 4.61 before the next release. Or would we have to install the new cert with the release?

If my understanding is correct, the algorithm is set in the certificate for the crypto service provider and would use the SHA256 algorithm from the re-issued certificate without modifications?

I do see in the registry under .../SCHANNEL/Hashes/SHA256 is enabled.

Comment: There are no SignedXML or SignedXML algorithms "in the cert". If you're getting an exception, please share the exception.

Comment: It's a CryptographicException "Invalid algorithm specified." which is caused by .NET versions from 4.71 and above defaulting to SHA256 and not allowing SHA1. Which is what the link I posted deals with in the .NET upgrade. But the more I look into certs and Cryptograhic Service Providers and look at what the .net code is doing the less any thing makes sense.

Comment: What is the code that you have that's throwing? What is the call stack from your code to where the exception is thrown?

Comment: I understand now what the issue is. It's using the "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" but what I need is the "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" to support SHA256. Looks like I'll have to have the certificate re-imported with the correct CSP.